# How to handle internal and external api access through API management?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have a scenario and need assistance when API are behind Azure API Management. In any organisation, They have both internal and external API.

In our organisation we have Azure API management and It is public to internet for clients. But we want to restrict all internal APIs not be exposed to internet. Is there any way to restrict this ?

exmaple:
www.myorganisation/apimanagement/internal/* --- Should not be accessible to internet.(accessible only in company network with valid JWT token)

www.myorganisation/apimanagement/external/* -- Should be accessible to internet with valid JWT token

We are using OKTA as our Oauth provider in Azure API management and validate JWT token inside each API policy.

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict access using API-M features like products, groups, users and
Subscriptions.

Internal product should be given access to internal users only - you can like an AD security group too.

External access should be controlled by the IT staff on case-to-case basis.

For example, the below Infra As Code in Bicep can be written to generate the products, group, subscription access in Azure API-M.

First create a Product:

```
module product'products/template.bicep' = {
  name: 'testProduct'
  params: {
    apimServiceName: apimServiceName
    productDescription: 'Product Project APIs'
    productDisplayName: 'Product Project'
    productName: 'ProductName'
    productSubscription: true
    productApproval: true
  }
}
```

Add the product to a Subscription:

```
module addSubsciptionToProduct 'subscriptions/template.bicep' = {
  name: 'subscriptionToProduct'
  params: {
    apimServiceName: apimServiceName
    scopeId: testProduct.outputs.productId
    subscriptionDisplayName: 'ProductSubscriptionKey'
    name: 'product-subscription-key'
    primaryKey: keyVault.getSecret('product-subscription-key')
  }
}
```

Create a group:

```
module group 'groups/template.bicep' = {
  name: 'groupDeployment'
  params: {
    apimServiceName: apimServiceName
    groupName: 'product-group'
    displayName: 'Product User Group'
  }
}
```

Then link Product to Group:

```
module productGroup 'product-group-links/template.bicep' = {
  name: 'prodcuctGroupDeployment'
  params: {
    apimServiceName: apimServiceName
    productGroupName: group.outputs.id
    productName: testProduct.outputs.productName
  }
}
```

you could also do all of this manually using click-ops in Azure portal.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. My requirement is different. I know about the APIM products and subscriptions. The idea is to block the traffic for external users if the api is meant for internal users. We are not using Microsoft AD as OAuth provider. I feel It should be possible by using Application Gateway in front of Api gateway. The request should not even reach to API management if the url pattern contains www.apimaagement/internal/testapi/